# How best to respond to an open HTTP range request

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, video-streaming, http-range

I am currently going through the process of attempting to respond to HTTP Range Requests so that video can be streamed from our server and also satisfy Safari actually playing the video.

I do have the added complication that the video file is encrypted on disk preventing me from being able to `Seek` in the stream but that is not really within the scope of this question.

I have noticed that Chrome and at least the new Edge request open ranges (0 - ). **What is the correct thing to respond with here?** Currently I respond with the full video which I understand completely defeats the purpose of streaming.

```
var range = context.Request.Headers["Range"].Split('=', '-');
var startByteIndex = int.Parse(range[1]);
// Quite a few browers send open ended requests for the range (e.g. 0- ).
long endByteIndex;
if (!long.TryParse(range[2], out endByteIndex))
{
    endByteIndex = streamLength - 1;
}
```

Below is my full attempt so far at responding.

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.Request.Headers["Range"]))
{
    var range = context.Request.Headers["Range"].Split('=', '-');
    var startByteIndex = int.Parse(range[1]);
    // Quite a few browers send open ended requests for the range (e.g. 0- ).
    long endByteIndex;
    if (!long.TryParse(range[2], out endByteIndex))
    {
        endByteIndex = streamLength - 1;
    }

    Debug.WriteLine("Range request for " + context.Request.Headers["Range"]);

    // Make sure the request is within the bounds of the video.
    if (endByteIndex >= streamLength)
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.RequestedRangeNotSatisfiable;
        return false;
    }

    var currentIndex = 0;

    // SEEKING IS NOT WHOLE AND COMPLETE.
    // Get to the requested start. We are not allowed to seek with CBC + AES.
    while (currentIndex < startByteIndex) // TODO: we could probably work out a more suitable buffer size here to get to the start index.
    {
        var dummy = new byte[bufferLength];

        var a = videoReadStream.Read(dummy, 0, bufferLength);
        currentIndex += bufferLength;
    }

    // Fast but unreliable given AES + CBC.
    //fileStream.Seek(startByteIndex, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    dataToRead = endByteIndex - startByteIndex + 1;

    // Supply the relevant partial content headers.
    context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.PartialContent;
    context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Range", $"bytes {startByteIndex}-{endByteIndex}/{streamLength}");
    context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", dataToRead.ToString());
}
else
{
    context.Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "private, max-age=1200");
    context.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(20));
    context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "inline;filename=" + fileID);

    context.Response.AddHeader("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");
}

var buffer = new byte[bufferLength];
while (dataToRead > 0 && context.Response.IsClientConnected)
{
    videoReadStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferLength);

    // Write the data to the current output stream.
    context.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);

    // Flush the data to the HTML output.
    context.Response.Flush();

    buffer = new byte[bufferLength];
    dataToRead -= bufferLength;
}
```

**Most frustratingly I notice that Edge (I haven't tested others yet) always seem to send an open request**

```
Range request for bytes=0-
Range request for bytes=1867776-
Range request for bytes=3571712-
Range request for bytes=5341184-
Range request for bytes=7176192-
Range request for bytes=9273344-
Range request for bytes=10977280-
Range request for bytes=12943360-
Range request for bytes=14614528-
Range request for bytes=16384000-
Range request for bytes=18087936-
Range request for bytes=19955712-
Range request for bytes=21823488-
Range request for bytes=23625728-
Range request for bytes=25690112-
Range request for bytes=27525120-
Range request for bytes=39256064-
Range request for bytes=41222144-
Range request for bytes=42270720-
```

Should I just decide on a chunk size to respond with and stick with that? I notice that if I did respond with chunks of just 3 in size then Edge does request a lot more ranges in increments of 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a similar, but not identical, question to [What byte range 0- means](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65063701/what-byte-range-0-means/65072254#65072254).

> What is the correct thing to respond with here?

The correct thing to respond with here is the entire resource. However, as this client included a `Range` header, you may *also* respond with a [`206 Partial content`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7233#section-4.1) and a subset of the file.

> Should I just decide on a chunk size to respond with and stick with that?

Pretty much, based on what's efficient for your server. Note that, as in [Firefox won't request further data after receiving 206 with specified content range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33237902/firefox-wont-request-further-data-after-receiving-206-with-specified-content-ra), you may encounter browsers that don't do the right thing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You certainly are correct when you say "you may encounter browsers that don't do the right thing" :).