# What byte range 0- means

Tags: http, http-1.1, http-range

What "Range: bytes=0-" header means ? Is the entire file ? I tried sending back 0 bytes and is not working, when I send the entire file it works, but I receive this request more than once in a streaming context, it doesn't look right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is the entire file ?

Yes, exactly that.

The spec has [the grammar](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7233#section-2.1):

```
     byte-range-set  = 1#( byte-range-spec / suffix-byte-range-spec )
     byte-range-spec = first-byte-pos "-" [ last-byte-pos ]
```

and also notes:

> If the last-byte-pos value is
> absent, or if the value is greater than or equal to the current
> length of the representation data, the byte range is interpreted as
> the remainder of the representation

Additionally:

> A client can request the last N bytes of the selected representation
> using a suffix-byte-range-spec.

```
     suffix-byte-range-spec = "-" suffix-length
```

So, valid examples from the spec include:

```
bytes=-500
bytes=9500-
bytes=0-0,-1
```

> I receive this request more than once in a streaming context

The header indicates that this client understands range requests, and would accept a [206 Partial Content](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7233#section-4.1) response, rather than the entire file, for efficient streaming ([What does the HTTP 206 Partial Content status message mean and how do I fully load resources?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15787380/what-does-the-http-206-partial-content-status-message-mean-and-how-do-i-fully-lo)).